# bookmarking and restoring dynamically added tabs

Tags: r, shiny, dynamic, bookmarks

I have a shiny app that dynamically add tabs to a tabset panel. When trying to use boookmarking in order to save the state and then restore it, I find that only the last added tab is being bookmarked.

I have tried using both bookmarking to the server as well as to URL. In both cases only the initial tabs (not added dynamically) plus the last dynamically added tab was bookmarked. All other dynamicalled added tabs were not bookmarked and thus did not appear when I restored the state.

Here is a reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
# example app for bookmarking and restoring dynamically added tabs
# only the last added tab is bookmarked. 

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add", "Add 'Dynamic' tab"),
      actionButton("remove", "Remove selected tab"), 
      # Add a bookmarking buttons
      bookmarkButton(),
      actionButton("restore", "Restore State")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Hello", "This is the hello tab")
      )
    )
  )
)
}
               
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(paste("Dynamic",input$add), "This a dynamically-added tab")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = input$tabs)
  })
  
  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    updateQueryString(url)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$restore, {
    session$reload() 
  }) 
}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this behaviour is by **design**. You see that your bookmark url contains the **value** of `input$add`:

[image: Screenshot of the URL of the Shiny app showing the address line which reads as http://127.0.0.1:5398/?inputs&tabs=%22Hello%22&remove=0&add=3&restore=0]

That is the value of `input$add` (3 in this case) is stored. Upon `restore` you set `input$add` to three, this fires your observer, which adds **one** dynamic panel (labeled *Dynamic 3*).

You need to store all added tabs and supply a "smarter" bookmark (restore) routine like this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ui <- function(request) {
   fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("add", "Add 'Dynamic' tab"),
            actionButton("remove", "Remove selected tab"), 
            # Add a bookmarking buttons
            bookmarkButton(),
            actionButton("restore", "Restore State")
         ),
         mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                        tabPanel("Hello", "This is the hello tab")
            )
         )
      )
   )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   dyn_tabs <- reactiveVal(NULL)
   added_tabs <- reactiveVal(NULL)
   cnt <- reactiveVal(0L)
   
   observeEvent(input$add, {
      cnt(cnt() + 1)
      id <- paste("Dynamic", cnt())
      dyn_tabs(c(dyn_tabs(), id))
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$remove, {
      remove_me <- input$tabs
      dyn_tabs(setdiff(dyn_tabs(), remove_me))
      added_tabs(setdiff(added_tabs(), remove_me))
      removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = remove_me)
   })
   
   observeEvent(dyn_tabs(), {
      new_tabs <- setdiff(dyn_tabs(), added_tabs())
      walk(new_tabs, ~ insertTab(inputId = "tabs", 
                                 tabPanel(.x, "This is a dynamically added tab")))
      added_tabs(union(added_tabs(), new_tabs))
   })
   
   setBookmarkExclude(c("add", "delete"))
   
   onBookmark(function(state) {
      state$values$dyn_tabs <- dyn_tabs()
      state$values$cnt <- cnt()
   })
   
   onBookmarked(function(url) {
      updateQueryString(url)
   })
   
   onRestored(function(state) {
      dyn_tabs(state$values$dyn_tabs)
      cnt(state$values$cnt)
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$restore, {
      session$reload()
   })
}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So basically we keep track about dynamic (but yet not *added*) panels (`dyn_tabs`) and save this vector upon bookmark. We keep also a list of *added* panels (`added_tabs`) in order not to re-render all panels upon change.

When we restore, we refill these vectors accordingly. We exclude `input$add` and  `input$remove` from the bookmarking to avoid that it adds (removes) its element upon restore.

However, we keep track about the number of previous clicks (`cnt`) in order to get a proper labeling.